# Playback volume from old Sony voice micro cassette recorder is very low

Tags: analog, audio, sound, recording

I have an old Sony V.O.R M-529V microcassette recorder. It was found in a box packed away years ago.

I put in some fresh batteries and tried to play some old micro cassettes I had, but the play back volume from the recorder even at full volume from the speaker was almost inaudible. I tried plugging in an earphone and the audio was a bit more audible but still quite low for full volume.

I tried a few different tapes but that did not make any difference. I tried changing the recording speed modes, but no change. I tried different batteries, again the same thing.

As a last resort I cleaned with some q-tip and head cleaning solution. Again, no change.

I opened up the recorder and see that the belt of the pulley is fine, the board also looks perfectly fine. No corrosion or damage of any kind inside.

Do you guys think the magnetic head is damaged or maybe the audio IC on the board is dead? Any suggestions on what I should look into?

**Update:** First of all thank you so much for the replies and suggestions. After looking at the feedback from you guys I decided to open up the recorder and inspect the head connections, the belt and the board components thoroughly. Head and belt seems to be fine.  But I did notice that after recording if I try to plug in a headphone or computer speaker via the 3.5mm jack the audio does play but had a lot of noise and distortion. But pressing down the [JRC 2128 IC](http://www.datasheetbank.com/datasheet-download/533364/1/JRC/NJM2128) made the sound louder and distortion sometimes reduced but was still present. I took a closer look and found the soldering connections had a slightly white crusty coating all over the connections on most components and some residual brown stuff mostly flux I guess. Which can be a a bit corrosive at time. Any way I put flux all over the board and reheated all the connections & reapplied solder and then cleaned it with ethyl alcohol. Then sprayed the volume pot and jacks with CRC co-cleaner contact.

Now I tried playing back and the volume from the main speaker was a lot louder but there was lot of distortion. I'm confused if this is a blown speaker or some issue with a component like a short SMD capacitor or something. But playback through the 3.5mm audio jack is perfectly fine now! :) The cassette on the right is okay but audio recorded on the left one seems to be the better. I tried recording a song and then playing back via the 3.5mm jack and its fine.

Also as KristoferA mentioned I need to change the electrolytics as they may have dried up. But the issue is some of the newer replacements of those values are much taller and will not allow the board to be seated.

[image: front]
[image: Board rear]
[image: Board front]
[image: micro cassette]

Comment: Did you try rerecording anything? Do you have a working device that is OK to test the tapes on?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, I tried a pre recorder and tried myself also recording. But the playback volume is quite low. More like extremely low.

Comment: So, you tried recording using the potentially faulty device and then you then put that newly recorded tape into a good device and established that it sounded OK. I ask for a reason because the chips used in playback are also quite often used when recording.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? This is when I'd start probing around and trying to see what level things are running at. Even better, do you have another one of these units that works fine? If you can compare the faulty unit to a known good one, it's almost trivial to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Though even if you don't have all that, my guess is something in the amplifier circuitry between the playback head and the output. Likely the preamplifier, since both the main speaker and the headphone output (which should use separate power amplifiers, I would think) show this problem. Though it *could* also be a power rail; you may have a faulty voltage regulator that's giving too little power to the amplifiers.

Comment: Gut feeling: old dried out catalytic capacitors somewhere along the way. If the thing has not been used for a long time, that can happen.

Comment: Magnetic tape is losing volume over the time. I guess it is old tapes you trying to record.

Comment: Hi, guys thank you for the replies. I have added an update to the original post and a few relevant pics of inside the recorder.

Comment: @Hearth I do have an old analog oscilloscope that I used to work on for my tube radio and amps a while back. Unfortunately, I do not have access to a working recorder anymore. I might try to see the input going to the chip and the output on the oscilloscope to see if there are any noise or distortions in the waveform. And like you said I need to check the voltage too.

Comment: @KristoferA It's possible the caps are dried. But the issue is finding the same caps with low profile. Most of the same value caps I checked in my local electronics store are much taller and I cannot use it on this board. Else it will not seat properly.

Comment: @user263983 Kindly, see my update in main post. The tapes seem to be recording fine. It's the audio playback that's the problem.